# Regular expression to align text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm new here. I was seeking for some help to get the following done with regex.

I have a MC tests lines like this:

```
Q1  I.......go to see the doctor last week because I was very ill.  
(a) must (b) must to    (c) had to (d) should to
Q2  I could.......bought that car but I didn't have enough money to pay for the petrol. 
(a) had (b) have    (c) have to (d) can
```

I would like the line from horizontal to vertical. That's it. It should look like this.

```
Q1  I.......go to see the doctor last week because I was very ill.  
(a) must
(b) must to
(c) had to
(d) should to

Q2  I could.......bought that car but I didn't have enough money to pay for the petrol. 
(a) had
(b) have
(c) have to
(d) can
```

I can't seem to make it work. That would save me long long hours of work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually it should look like this:                                                                                        Q1 I.......go to see the doctor last week because I was very ill.
(a) must
(b) must to
(c) had to
(d) should to

Q2 I could.......bought that car but I didn't have enough money to pay for the petrol.
(a) had
(b) have
(c) have to
(d) can

Comment: Where do you want to apply the regex? Text editor? Program? If so, in which language?

Comment: I have problem with inserting the text as it should look like. I need this in Notepad ++

Comment: Did my edit to your question make it correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks now correct. It should be vertical not horizontal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
(\([b-d]\))
```

<sup>* *this is for a-d answers, change `d` for the maximum possible answer*</sup>

Replace with:

```
\r\n$1
```

Input:

```
Q1  I.......go to see the doctor last week because I was very ill.  
(a) must (b) must to    (c) had to (d) should to
Q2  I could.......bought that car but I didn't have enough money to pay for the petrol. 
(a) had (b) have    (c) have to (d) can
```

Output:

```
Q1  I.......go to see the doctor last week because I was very ill.  
(a) must 
(b) must to    
(c) had to 
(d) should to
Q2  I could.......bought that car but I didn't have enough money to pay for the petrol. 
(a) had 
(b) have    
(c) have to 
(d) can
```

Is this enough?

If you want to separate questions with newlines, you can also search for: `^Q(?!1\b)(\d*)\b` and replace with `\r\nQ$1`. That will insert a newline before all questions except for #1

Comment: `[b-z]` probably. And then replace `^Q\d` with another `\r\n$1`. :)

Comment: @bipll according to his question, there's just `[b-d]`... I added the Qx on a update, excepting #1 :-)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time :) Where shall I send you the beer? :) Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah, sure, #1. On 'd' or 'z', the question is formulated in terms of 'like' so I fancy it'll be safer that way. :)

Comment: @bipll I added a note ;-)

Comment: @Aron use the tick mark right next to the votes. Check [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information :-)

Comment: I was just wondering if it is possible to insert the following word "Answer: " after each and every (d) line, and after the line that contains "Answer: ", there should be an empty line?

Comment: @Aron after they are already "vertical", search for `^\(d\)(.*)$`, replace with: `\(d\)$1\r\nAnswer:\r\n`... add `\r\n` as necessary at the end